# What is the trick behind this code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

why does this give me a result as DATETIME ?

```
Select DATEADD(yy,116, 0)
```

Output:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

and this

```
Select DATEADD(yy,116 +1, -1)
```

Returns me last day of the year?

What is the trick behind this? I was just playing with it but don't get how it came?

Comment: Which part do you not understand, exactly? Could you give a little more detail on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flogging a dead horse on this one but here's my explanation.

`DATEADD(yy...` is adding years to the given date. (As an aside, the abbreviated forms are evil, you should use `DATEADD(YEAR,...)` for clarity).

Date `0` is, as everyone else has said, Midnight, Monday, January 1st, 1900. Date `-1` is Sunday, December 31st 1899, 1 day before.

If you add `116+1` to Date `-1` you get December 31st, (1899 + 117) = 2016. 
You could also write this as `SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,117, '1899-12-31')` or numerous other ways using date literals.

**Bonus**

As to *why* it's returning a `Datetime` as opposed to a `Datetime2`, a `Smalldatetime` or any other type, `DATEADD` returns whatever type you pass as the date parameter. `-1` is converted implicitly (as per the normal cast/convert rules) to a Datetime - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx.

If you want to see this in action, this code will show you the result of feeding `DATEADD` with different types:

```
SELECT
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(GETDATE(), 'BaseType') BaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 'BaseType') DateAddBaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME2)), 'BaseType') DateAddDatetime2,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS SMALLDATETIME)), 'BaseType') DateAddSmallDatetime,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATETIME2, GETDATE() )), 'BaseType') DateAddDatetime2Convert
```

**Extra Bonus**

If you want the last day of the current year:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

Or if you want the last resolvable datetime2 of the current year (ie 100ns before midnight new year's day):

```
SELECT DATEADD(NANOSECOND, -100,CAST(DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE())+1,0) AS DATETIME2(7)))
```

Examine each of these, and hopefully you'll be able to work out what they're doing.

Comment: You may be flogging a dead horse but your answer is the most comprehensive yet. I think it might be a bit too much for this question, but you got my vote anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Date `0` is `1900-01-01` ,

So Date `-1` is `1899-12-31` ie (reduce 1 day from `1900-01-01`)

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 0) : Result is 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

So `Select DATEADD(yy,116 +1, -1)` will add 116+1 (ie 117) year to 1899

(`117 years will add to 1899-12-31 00:00:00.000`)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server datetimes are based on the number of days since `1900-01-01`.

```
 0 = 1900-01-01
-1 = 1899-12-31
```

Now you add 116 years to #1 and you add 117 years to #2.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server stores datetime values as 8 bytes - the first 4 bytes represents the number of days from January 1st, 1900, and the last 4 bytes represents the number of ticks since midnight (a tick is 3.3 milliseconds, that's why datetime accuracy limit is 3.3 ms).

So, when converting `0` to a datetime value, you get `1900-01-01`.
when converting `1` you get `1900-01-02`,
and when converting `-1` you get `1899-12-31`.

so, simple math - adding 116 years to 1900 will give 2016.
adding 117 years to 1899-12-31 will result in 2016-12-31.

For more information about datetime storage in sql server you can read [this article.](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery)